# An unexpected error occurs when trying to use UiApp.add() method in a script that previously functioned well

Tags: google-apps-script

An unexpected error occurs when trying to use UiApp.add() method in a script that previously functioned well. The problem appeared today.

I've struggled to make some workaround but no luck.

Anybody has the same problems?
Were any changes made to the method, especiallysmth about naming restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

I never saw `add()` method in `UiApp`. I don't know how it was working previously in your case?
As the documentation says, there are only three methods of this class, no `add()` method

```
createApplication
getActiveApplication
getUserAgent
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp

You can use add method with an instance of application.
e.g

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var toggleButton = app.createToggleButton();
  toggleButton.setText('Click Me');
  panel.add(toggleButton); //Add a UI Widget
  app.add(panel); // Add a UI Widget
  return app;
}
```

Comment: The script was written win accordance to your example, so the problem was a different one. Saurabh Gupta already helped resolve it. Sincere thanks to him

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1384) that cropped up, and is now fixed. When you discover a bug it's best to post it to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/) rather than here on Stack Overflow.